# Select slice of dataframe according to value of multiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a multiIndex dataframe.

I am able to create a logical mask using the following:

`df.index.get_level_values(0).to_series().str.find('1000')!=-1`

This returns a boolean `True` for all the rows where the first index level contains the characters `'1000'`and `False` otherwise.

But I am not able to slice the dataframe using that mask.

I tried with:

```
df[df.index.get_level_values(0).to_series().str.find('1000')!=-1]
```

and it returned the following error:

`ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

I also tried with:

```
df[df.index.get_level_values(0).to_series().str.find('1000')!=-1,:]
```

which only returns the logic mask as output and the following error:

```
Length: 1755, dtype: bool, slice(None, None, None))' is an invalid key
```

Can someone point me to the right solution and to a good reference on how to slice properly a multiIndex dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is remove `to_series()` and use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for test substring:

```
df[df.index.get_level_values(0).str.contains('1000')]
```

Another is convert mask to numpy array:

```
df[df.index.get_level_values(0).str.contains('1000').values]
```

Your solution with converting values of mask to array:

```
df[(df.index.get_level_values(0).to_series().str.find('1000')!=-1).values]
```